# Periodic STDIN for a bash command through Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bash, subprocess, stdin

I have a simple C++ program:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  while(1) {
    string s;
    cout << "Enter command: ";
    cin >> s;
    if (s == "end") {
      break;
    }
    cout << "Sent command: " << s << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to read a set of commands from another file, say cmd.txt as below:

```
start
go 10
r 20
go 10
stop
end
```

and so on. But it should be periodic, i.e.,

1. read `start`; wait for 1 minute
2. read `go 10`; wait for 1 minute... and so on.

To solve this, I thought I can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) from Python 3 and then issue the bash command with stdin being read from the file and supplied periodically. But, the command seems to be blocking in the first place itself.

Here is the script that I have tried so far:

```
import subprocess
patterns = ['rectangle.txt', 'hexagon.txt']

subprocess.run(["g++", "reads.cpp", "-o", "reads"], shell=True)

for ptr in patterns:
  print('Testing commands from ', ptr)
  subprocess.run(["./reads"], shell=True)
  commands = open(ptr, 'r').readlines()
  for cmd in commands:
    print(cmd, end='')
```

So, how can I achieve this? Or should I use only Bash for this?